# UWP ListView not scrolling vertically

Tags: listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

After adding a `ListView` inside a `Grid`, it doesn't scroll vertically for some reason. I've placed the `ListView` inside a `ScrollViewer` then taken it out again and that still didn't make a difference. What needs to be done to fix this and add a vertical scroll bar so the user is aware that all content can't fit their screen?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock x:Uid="Header" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" />
        <TextBlock Text="SubHeader" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind listItems}"
                SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyApp.ContactPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock x:Uid="Header" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" />
            <TextBlock Text="SubHeader" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView 
                Grid.Row="1"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind listItems}" 
                SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                                       Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that you set the second row, `ListView`'s height to `Auto`, which means it will stretch to the max height, in order to show it's content. If you have a long enough screen, you can see the result.

But we usually do not set a `ListView`/`GridView`'s height to `Auto`, we can set it's height to a fix value. Or you can use * instead.
* means it will the the rest of your window height. so you can change your code like this.

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

As the above code shows, the first row will stretch its height automaticaly, the second row will take the rest of you window height.

You can also set more *.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The above code shows that the second and the third row will take half of the rest height each.

[image]

Comment: Changing to that didn't make any difference. See updated code.

Comment: Can you paste the a screenshot of your app. It runs ok and shows the vertical scroll bar here.

Comment: The explanation sounds good, but the solution doesn't work.